# Cannot truncate a table using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I try to truncate a table from a Python application using psycopg2. The operation returns -1 without either exception or any indication of a problem. The table is not truncated. The statement itself is correct as it works when I run it via psql.

Both DB server and client are RHEL 7.6. I use PostgreSQL 11.2, Python 2.75 and psycopg2 2.5.1.3el7

The code is very simple:

```
m_dbCon = psycopg2.connect(user=dbUser, password=dbPasswd, host=dbHost, port=dbPort, database=dbInstName)
curr = m_dbCon.cursor()
curr.execute('truncate table my_table')
count = curr.rowcount
curr.close()
```

As I've said no exception is thrown and the ***count*** is ***-1***.

I could not find any explanation for this issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any foreign keys referencing that table?

Comment: No. The same statement from works in psql.

Comment: You might need to commit after execute: `m_dbCon.commit()`

Comment: I ran truncate with and without commit. The result is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just a typo or not, but your cursor is created from self.m_dbCon, but you create m_dbCon in the previous line.  Are these two different objects?  When you tried committing, was the table empty afterwards?  I think truncate will always return -1 because it is avoiding the overhead of counting rows.  Use delete if you need the rowcount.

Comment: It's a typo. I use *m_dbCon* at all places. You are correct about *rowcount*. It worked correctly when I ignored this -1. Thanks.

Comment: I have this self same problem with psycopg2 alas, postgreSQL 14, python 3.10. Love it when I find people who have my very problem and still no solution 2 years later. Oh well. If I find one I may be back.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use:

conn.commit()

in order to save the changes made to the db permanently.

Check this:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/delete/

Comment: Tried this after a TRUNCATE but still see no impact on the database when inspected with pgadmin4.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy stated in the comments, *rowcount* should be ignored in case of TRUNCATE.

I believe that absence of an exception means success of the statement . At least, it is so in this case.